# How do you get the first 3 elements in Python OrderedDict?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

How do you get the first 3 elements in Python OrderedDict?

Also is it possible to delete data from this dictionary.

For example: How would I get the first 3 elements in Python OrderedDict and delete the rest of the elements?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Let's create a simple `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict(enumerate("abcdefg"))
>>> od
OrderedDict([(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f'), (6, 'g')])
```

To return the first three *keys*, *values* or *items* respectively:

```
>>> list(od)[:3]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list(od.values())[:3]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(od.items())[:3]
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

To remove everything except the first three items:

```
>>> while len(od) > 3:
...     od.popitem()
... 
(6, 'g')
(5, 'f')
(4, 'e')
(3, 'd')
>>> od
OrderedDict([(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')])
```

Comment: `.items()` and `.values()` return lists (at least in Python 2.7) so there is no need to use `list()`. Is it different in Python 3?

Comment: @John [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views). I chose not to complicate the answer by mentioning that in 2.x lists are returned: there's no practical impact here, and in any case, everyone should by now be writing with 3.x in mind (even if their code doesn't yet target it).

Comment: It is worth noting that `OrderedDict(list(od.items())[:3])` will return a dict with only the first three items in a one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this iterative method to get the job done.

```
x = 0
for i in ordered_dict:
    if x > 3:
        del ordered_dict[i]
    x += 1
```

First, you just make a counter variable, `x`, and assign it to 0. Then you cycle through the keys in `ordered_dict`. You see how many items have been checked by seeing it `x` is greater than 3, which is the number of values you want. If 3 items have already been checked, you `del`ete that item from `ordered_dict`.

---

Here is a cleaner, alternative method (thanks to the comments)

```
for i, k in enumerate(ordered_dict):
    if i > 2:
        del ordered_dict[k]
```

This works by using enumerate to assign a number to each key. Then it checks if that number is less than two (0, 1, or 2). If the number is not 0, 1, or 2 (these will be the first three elements), then that item in the dictionary will be deleted.

Comment: Ah, I see where you're going with that. My bad. You could use `enumerate` here instead.

Comment: Nvm, but yeah, enumerate is better.

Comment: Something like this: `for i, k in enumerate(odct): if i > 2: del odct[k]` Obviously, not on one line because that's a syntax error :p

Comment: Note that this solution fails for python3 with n `RuntimeError` as the size of the dictionary is not allowed to change during iteration

Answer (score 2):

It's not different from other dicts:

```
d = OrderedDict({ x: x for x in range(10) })

i = d.iteritems()
a = next(i)
b = next(i)
c = next(i)

d = OrderedDict([a,b,c])
# or
d.clear()
d.update([a,b,c])
```